# How to extract $O(h^2)$ from $f\left(t_{i+1},y_i+hf(t_i,y_i)+O(h^2)\right)$

Tags: asymptotics

This is the formula of [explicit Heun's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun's_method)
$$
y_{i+1}=y_i+hf\left(t_{i+1},y_i+hf(t_i,y_i)+O(h^2)\right)+O(h^3)
$$
and I want to prove that this formula is $O(h^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

$y_{i+1}=y_i+hf\left(t_{i+1},y_i+hf(t_i,y_i)+O(h^2)\right)+O(h^3)=y_i+h(f\left(t_{i+1},y_i+hf(t_i,y_i)\right)+f'(t_{i+1},y_i+hf(t_i,y_i))O(h^2))+O(h^3)=y_i+hf\left(t_{i+1},y_i+hf(t_i,y_i)\right)+O(h^3)$

Comment: How did you achieve it?

Comment: First order taylor serie approximation?